# Weighted secret sharing scheme?

Tags: secret-sharing, information-theory

Is there a secret sharing scheme where secrets can be weighted, and that you need a total weight of $1$ to unlock the secret?

I know that you could, of course, just figure out every subset that has access to the secret and then do a [XOR secret sharing scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_sharing#1_.3C_t_.3C_n.2C_and.2C_more_general.2C_any_desired_subset_of_n), but that isn't very efficient.

Comment: @RickyDemer I'm considering the general case, where this may not be the case.